# Unable to create folder in class library in asp.net.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application that include a reference which will create a new folder when the reference's method is called.

However i have an error when my application call the method.

```
Access to the path 'TempPDFStorage/' is denied.
```

I try the same thing in windows form. It have no issue and the new folder will be created in the bin/debug/

What should i do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to access this path on the client machine or server?  If you have rights to IIS you can impersonate a user for your application that has rights to that directory and you should be fine then.

To set the security context of a user with permissions:

1. Open up IIS Manager (Run -> "inetmgr")
2. Locate your web application
3. Click on your web application and on the right side click "Basic Settings..."
4. Click "Connect as..."
5. Select "Specific User"
6. Click "Set..."
7. Enter the credentials of the user with permissions to that directory

Conversely, to impersonate as an unauthenticated user you can do this:

1. Follow the above steps 1 and 2
2. On the Features View double click "Authentication"
3. Depending on how you have authentication set up you can configure the "Anonymous" to use specific credentials (by default it is set to IUSR)

Comment: on server. so what should i do?

Comment: @DEN check out my Edit on my post.  That should allow you to modify the context of your user.

Comment: can't proceed after step 2. after i click on the web application, it only show me the folder and aspx file. it doesn't have Basic Settings

Comment: @DEN do you not see the "Actions" section on the right side?  What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: dear @shark , http://images.static-webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/images/installing_iis_winXP_iis_console.gif the image link is similar with my inetmgr. check it out

Comment: unfortunately,it doesn't state what version of my IIS is. but the os is microsoft server 2003

Comment: Click on "Help" -> "About IIS..." or something along those lines to get the version.

Comment: ya. i did. it just show me "Internet Information Services(IIS) Manager Microsoft Corporation"

Comment: @DEN maybe you can try something like this: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4ec9116c-7ca2-4126-9dc4-b7f82b67cd76.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: i have read the article and set <identity impersonate="true"/> , but the result is just the same. I guess i have to go for another alternative of accessing the folder.

Comment: @DEN Set it in full.  You need to provide credentials in your `<identity />` tag.  Like so: `<identity impersonate="true" userName="contoso\Jane" password="pass"/>`

Comment: thanks for your solution. However, it will b better if i just create the folder using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory . I will mark your question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A web application is normaly only executed on the server and has with standard settings no write privilages on a desktop. A winform executes on the desktop. I think what you want to do is not a very good praktice for security.

Comment: so what's the better practise for this? since i need to create a new folder when calling the method of the reference.